# Construct a doubly periodic function on $\mathbb{C}$ using Jacobi elliptic functions with anti-holomorphic involution

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, special-functions, theta-functions, elliptic-functions

I would like to find explicit examples of non-constant meromorphic doubly periodic $f(z)$ on $\mathbb{C}$, i.e. a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C} / \Gamma$ for some lattice $\Gamma$, such that there exists some anti-holomorphic involution $\rho: \mathbb{C} /\Gamma \rightarrow \mathbb{C} /\Gamma$, and $f$ satisfies:

$$\begin{equation} f( \rho (z) ) = 1 / \overline{f(z)} \tag{1} \end{equation}$$

My first thought was to find a Jacobi elliptic function which satisfies these requirements, however one quickly runs into problems. If we choose $f(z) = \mathbb{sn}(z,k)$, this has periods $2iK'$ and $4K$ (see https://dlmf.nist.gov/22.4 for more details on the periods), so the lattice would be $\Gamma = 2iK' \mathbb{Z} + 4K \mathbb{Z}$. Now, to construct an anti-holomorphic involution satisfying (1), I've come up with 2 candidates.

$$\rho(z) = \bar{z} + i K',$$
$$\rho(z) = \bar{z} + i K' + 2K.$$

However both of these come up with problems:

$$ \mathbb{sn}(\bar{z} + i K',k ) = \frac{1}{k\> \mathbb{sn}(\bar{z})} $$
$$ \mathbb{sn}(\bar{z} + i K' + 2K,k ) = \frac{-1}{k\> \mathbb{sn}(\bar{z})} $$

So for $k \neq 1$, this involution wont satisfy $(1)$ and if $k \rightarrow 1$ then $\mathbb{sn}(z,k) \rightarrow \mathbb{tanh}(z)$, which is no longer doubly periodic on any finite lattice. Am I right in assuming that all the other Jacobi Elliptic functions will run into the same kind of problems? Additionally would anyone know how to construct such a function using the [Theta functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/20.2) instead?

Comment: Consider $\Gamma = \mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $\rho(z)=\bar{z}$. By the theory of elliptic functions, there exists a meromorphic function $f$ with a zero of order $N$ at $z=i/N$ and a pole of order $N$ at $z=-i/N$. Since $\rho$ exchanges the zero and the pole, you will get $f(\bar{z}) = c/\overline{f(z)}$ for some nonzero constant $c$, which must be real. You can then scale $f$ to get $c=1$. It's possible to make such an $f$ explicit with the Weierstrass or theta functions.

Comment: Oh, I can't believe I didn't see that. Setting f(z) = $\sqrt{k} \mathbb{sn}(z,k)$ will work